# PlayOnLinux Origin Lab 8 Unable to launch Excel

Tags: playonlinux

I have installed office 2010 and origin Lab 8 with PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 14.04 but when i try to open new Excel this message appear "Origin is Unable to launch Excel. Please make sure that Excel is properly installed. If Excel is already installed on your computer, you may need to restart windows."

Comment: POL installs every software in its own environment. Meaning one cannot access other environments. To the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

PlayOnLinux first creates a environment that will remain separate, also known as a [Wine Prefix](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-f54d469b937b82e6d757a851dfcece0167919859). Then it will install the software in the separate Wine Prefix. Meaning - To the best of my knowledge - one cannot access other environments.

What you can try is, install one software in to the other Wine Prefix. We will use Origin lab for this. As you mentioned, you already installed Origin lab 8. To avoided confusion I suggest to remove it before continuing.

Go to the PlayOnLinux Microsoft Office configuration screen and select `Miscellaneous` then click `run a .exe file in this virtual drive`. Search and select the `Origin Lab 8 setup.exe`, follow the setup wizard and afterwards it should be installed. Search for `Origin Lab 8` via the unity Dash or via PlayOnLinux.

[image: PlayOnLinux - Configuration - Miscellaneous]

<sup>Image excerpt from: [Dikkii's Diatribe: How to get round DRM issues with e-books in Linux (epub)](http://dikkiisdiatribe.blogspot.nl/2013/01/how-to-get-round-drm-issues-with-e.html)</sup>

Due note that both Wine Prefixes(Office, origin) are specifically customized for those applications. Installing one in the other might not prove fruitful.

Comment: thank you blade i followed your instructions, making a new shortcut of Origin from that virtual drive, but the problem still persist, when trying to open new Excel it opens and closes immediately and the same message still appear "Origin is Unable to launch Excel. Please make sure that Excel is properly installed. If Excel is already installed on your computer, you may need to restart windows."

Comment: @artf78, did you reboot Ubuntu? You can fake a Windows reboot, see screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lM9hl.png

Comment: I reboot ubuntu and Nothing happens when i reboot windows as it shown in the link.

Comment: @artf78 For now, I can't help you as I am not near an Ubuntu machine! I'll try some things out when I get to one. Curious about this myself!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a Windows application is installed through PlayOnLinux, a separate Wine prefix is created.

Therefore, your Micrsoft Excel and Origin are installed in separate and isolated virtual C drives, which explains why Origin is not able to access Excel.

The solution to your problem is to install both the programs in the same wine prefix.